# Downvote suggestion layout issue

Tags: bug, design

I was downvoting a question today, and I noticed an issue with the tags behind the blue suggestion box. Part of the tags are behind but the triangles in the end are in-front. The tags in the question are `c++` and `mmo`.

[image: Downvote layout issue]

Comment: What browser were you using for this, just curious? It took me some time to find a question with tags in the right position, but I wasn't able to repro on my end, so knowing which browsers it is breaking on would be keen.

Comment: It's a long time ago, so probably whatever was the latest Firefox at the time.

Comment: Out of curiosity, then, does it no longer persist for you in your current rendition of Firefox?